# How to spawn objects only in certain Tiled Layer (Phaser)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, game-development, tiled

I am trying to create a simple Phaser game using Tiled but I have a problem. I want to spawn the flasks only in a certain layer (the layer that is the floor, which is layer[3]) so that they don't overlap with the other layers. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.
'

```
        layers[1] = this.map.createLayer('1');
        layers[2] = this.map.createLayer('2');
        layers[3] = this.map.createLayer('3');
        this.flasks = this.game.add.group();
        this.flasks.enableBody = true;
        this.flasks.scale.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
        for (var i = 0; i <20 ; i++)
    {
        var flask = this.flasks.create(game.world.randomX, game.world.randomY, 'flask');
    }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really add the flasks to a layer. You rather draw those items after your desired layer.
Store the items you want to show (like enemy drops) in a data structure (e.g. a list) and draw those items after your 3rd layer.